# Texture filtering DirectX to WebGL

Tags: opengl-es, directx, textures, webgl

We're porting and old code written in DirectX 9 to WebGL. We stumbled with a bug, that seems to be related to the texture filtering.

The original code used the following, for some textures:

```
MinFilter = LINEAR;
MagFilter = LINEAR;
MipFilter = POINT;    
Texture   = <envCube1>;
AddressU  = WRAP;
AddressV  = WRAP;
```

And this for others:

```
MinFilter = POINT;
MagFilter = POINT;
MipFilter = POINT;    
Texture   = <envCube4>;
AddressU  = WRAP;
AddressV  = WRAP;
```

I know that the MagFilter is POINT = NEAREST and LINEAR = LINEAR, but since WebGL (and OpenGL in general) does not separate the MipFilter from the MinFilter I'm not sure which is the equivalent.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

#### Given the two sampler states from DX9, the OpenGL equivalent setups are:

```
Min Filter: GL_NEAREST_MIPMAP_LINEAR
Mag Filter: GL_LINEAR
```

#### and

```
Min Filter: GL_NEAREST_MIPMAP_NEAREST
Mag Filter: GL_NEAREST
```

---

In more general terms, there is a rule of thumb that you need to observe.

The min filter in OpenGL is where they decided to tack on the mip filter as a sort of after-the-fact hack (quite a bit of GL's design amounts to quick hacks to make something fit the existing API without introducing new commands or states).

Any filter constant with `..._MIPMAP_...` in it is only valid for use as a minification filter and reads this way:

```
GL_<MipFilter>_MIPMAP_<MinFilter>
```

---

#### Your question did not ask this, but consider the following D3D sampler state:

```
MinFilter = POINT
MagFilter = POINT
MipFilter = NONE
```

#### Here is its GL equivalent setup:

```
MinFilter = GL_NEAREST
MagFilter = GL_NEAREST
```